# iOS VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame error -12909 when decoding HEVC

Tags: ios, video-streaming, hevc, h.265, video-toolbox

I have some trouble with streaming raw H.265 over rtsp when using VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame. The 3 main steps I do are the following ones:

```
OSStatus status = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromHEVCParameterSets(kCFAllocatorDefault, 3, parameterSetPointers, parameterSetSizes, (int)kNALUHeaderSize, NULL, &formatDescription);

OSStatus status = VTDecompressionSessionCreate(NULL, formatDescription, NULL, NULL, &decompressionCallBack, &_decompressionSession);

VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame(self.decompressionSession, sampleBuffer, flags, (void *)CFBridgingRetain(currentTime), NULL);
```

The format description looks like this:

```
<CMVideoFormatDescription 0x1c0044d10 [0x1b2bb1310]> {
mediaType:'vide' 
mediaSubType:'hvc1' 
mediaSpecific: {
    codecType: 'hvc1'       dimensions: 640 x 360 
} 
extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x1c00742c0 [0x1b2bb1310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 10,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x1ab8dd470 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "SampleDescriptionExtensionAtoms"} = <CFBasicHash 0x1c0074140 [0x1b2bb1310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
0 : hvcC = <CFData 0x1c01678c0 [0x1b2bb1310]>{length = 115, capacity = 115, bytes = 0x01016000000000008000000042f000fc ... 4401d172b0942b12}
}

1 : <CFString 0x1ab8b8ff8 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x1ab8b9018 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
2 : <CFString 0x1ab8b92b8 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField"} = <CFString 0x1ab8b92f8 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "Left"}
3 : <CFString 0x1ab8b8f38 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVPixelAspectRatio"} = <CFBasicHash 0x1c0074280 [0x1b2bb1310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
1 : <CFString 0x1ab8b8f58 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "HorizontalSpacing"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000012 [0x1b2bb1310]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
2 : <CFString 0x1ab8b8f78 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "VerticalSpacing"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000012 [0x1b2bb1310]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

5 : <CFString 0x1ab8b90d8 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x1ab8b9018 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
6 : <CFString 0x1ab8dd670 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "FullRangeVideo"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b2bb1868 [0x1b2bb1310]>{value = true}
8 : <CFString 0x1ab8b9158 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0x1ab8b9018 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
10 : <CFString 0x1ab8b92d8 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationBottomField"} = <CFString 0x1ab8b92f8 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "Left"}
11 : <CFString 0x1ab8ddc10 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "BitsPerComponent"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000080 [0x1b2bb1310]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt8Type}
12 : <CFString 0x1ab8b8e78 [0x1b2bb1310]>{contents = "CVFieldCount"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000012 [0x1b2bb1310]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}
}
}
```

When decoding a frame I get the OSStatus -12909 in the decompression callback. Therefore, I think that the VPS, PPS and SPS is correctly handled when creating the format description. The Decompression session is also successfully created. I can also successfully decode and render a HEVC stream, for example this one:
The solution also work when streaming raw H.264 if CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromHEVCParameterSets is changed to CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets.

Any ideas what can be wrong? Is the format description even supported? Sadly there isn't to much documentation about HEVC decoding from Apples side.
I can stream my H.265 stream if using ffmpeg so I guess the stream should be correctly formated.